# Converting non-standard date format (e.g., "5 Sep") to dd/mm (e.g., 05/09)

Tags: excel, vb.net, date

I have a VB.NET problem, whereby I want to convert non-standard dates in the header row of an Excel spreadsheet into a different format. Specifically, the worksheet arrives with an alphanumeric string variable day and month (e.g., "5 Sep") but I need it convert that to another string as "05/09".

Unfortunately, I neither create these worksheets nor define myself what the output format should be - so stuck between a rock and a hard place. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've wasted two days getting nowhere so far! Many thanks in advance.

```
                Try
                    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(result2)
                    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Attendances")

                    xlWorkBook.Activate()
                    If xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Course" Then
                        xlWorkSheet.Rows(1 & ":" & 3).Delete()
                        xlWorkBook.Save()



                        For t As Integer = 6 To 75
                            If xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, t).Value <> "" And Len(xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, t).Value) > 25 Then
                                xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, t).Value = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, t).Value, InStr(xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, t).Value, " 20") - 1)
                            End If
                        Next                           

                        xlWorkBook.Save()
                        xlWorkBook.Close()
                    End If
                    xlApp.Quit()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    lblPath.Text = "Exception"
                End Try
```

Comment: Are you sure the date is actually `5 Sep` or is it just how Excel displays it?

Comment: Please put some code in your question showing the vb.net used to read the Excel doc and your attempt to read and convert the date cell

Comment: You have to know what the possible date formats are in order to parse the text. You can call `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` and specify multiple formats to convert to a `Date` and then call `ToString` with whatever final format you want.

Comment: The date is actually "5 Sep", since it starts out as "5 Sep 2021 2.20PM All students". I've parsed the string and deleted everything to the right of "5 Sep", but that still leaves me with the problem I'm describing.

Comment: jmcilhinney it does start out as a date but a string "6 Sep 2021 2.20PM All students" which is quite useless. Like I said to djv, I can strip it down as far as "6 Sep", but that's not a recognized date format. I'm thinking about brute force parsing it through if-then statements, then reconstructing it.

Comment: Hi Andrew, yes I can do that. Indeed, I think that was one of my strategies that failed (but the core idea is still a good one). The problem is compounded by the fact I then have to work in UK dd/mm format against another file. But sure, it's easily doable.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks! That worked. Much appreciated. - Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you retain the year part, you can use the DateTime.Parse function. Then you can convert the resulting DateTime to a string with only the parts you want.

```
For t As Integer = 6 To 75
    Dim v = xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, t).Value
    If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v)) AndAlso Len(v) > 25 Then
        Dim sd = String.Join(" ", v.Split({" "c}, 4).Take(3))
        Dim d = DateTime.Parse(sd, New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"))
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, t).Value = $"=""{d.ToString("dd/MM")}"""
    End If
Next
```

The value is of the form `="05/09"` so that Excel doesn't format it like a date and doesn't do the division. Maybe you don't need to force it like that.

I suggest that the original data be kept somewhere, perhaps by hiding the column, and a new column is used for the display.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I got it to work by brute forcing a split(" ",c) and then if-thening all combinations of twelve months (which was always the horrible way of doing this). But I'm going to try you code as it's the "proper" way to do. My problem is that the input data comes from the attendance rosters in the Moodle LMS system, and they've just reformatted all of it, so not only does my old code not work, but I have to try and fit their new format into old software - which is harder that starting from scratch! But many, many thanks. I'll post how I get on. - Peter

Comment: @user8226676 You're welcome :) You might want to use [DateTime.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse) instead, as that gives a clean way to avoid exceptions if the data is malformed - you could save up the line numbers where it went wrong and then show them to the user for manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:

```
Private Function GetMonthNumber%(s$)

Select Case UCase(Trim(s$))
    Case "JAN"
     Return 1
    Case "FEB"
     Return 2
    '...
    Case Else
    'bad argument
    Return 0 
End Select
End Function
```